# OpenCV changing VideoCapture resolution causes colour issues and glitches

Tags: python, opencv

I want to capture 1920x1080 video from my camera but I've run into two issues

1. When I initialize a VideoCapture, it changes the width/height to 640/480
2. When I try to change the width/height in cv2, the image becomes messed up

## Images

When setting 1920x1080 in cv2, the image becomes blue and has a glitchy bar at the bottom

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
```

[image: 1920x1080 distorted image]

Here's what's happening according to v4l2-ctl. The blue image doesn't seem to be a result of a pixelformat change (eg. RGB to BGR)

[image]

And finally, here's an example of an image being captured at 640x480 that has the correct colouring. The only difference in the code is that width/height is not set in cv2

[image]

Comment: Simplest question first: does the camera support this new resolution? In terms of ressolution itself and also regarding aspect ratio (16:9 versus 4:3)

Comment: What are the specs of the camera (e.g. what is the framerate the camera supports at 1080p ? (e.g. 15 / 24 / 30 / 60 /etc.)) ? How fast are you retrieving frames ?

Comment: It's a [raspi cam v2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) and it claims to support 1080p at 30fps, I'm running at 12fps. Perhaps it could still be aspect ratio related though... is there another way to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem:

Actually the camera you are using has 2 mode:

1. 640x480
2. 1920x1080

One is for main stream, one is for sub stream. I also met this problem couple of times and here is the possible reasons why it doesn't work.

***Note:** I assume you tried different ways to run on full resolution(1920x1080) such as `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` , `cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` , `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` ...*

## Possible reasons

1. First reason could be that the camera doesn't support the resolution you desire but in your case we see that it supports 1920x1080 resolution. So this can not be the reason for your isssue.
2. Second reason which is general reason is that [opencv backend](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d) doesn't support your camera driver. Since you are using **VideoCaptureProperties** of opencv, [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) says:

> Reading / writing properties involves many layers. Some unexpected result might happens along this chain. Effective behaviour depends from device hardware, driver and API Backend.

## What you can do:

In this case, if you really need to reach that resolution and make compatible with opencv, you should use the SDK of your camera(if it has).